# ASP.NET Core select tag

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I am learning asp .net core, and for that purpose I am developing simple blogging application. I want to edit existing post and I want to have dropdown with categories of posts but to have selected by default current category of the post. I am failing to do it on the view.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
namespace Blog.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class CategoryViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }

  var posts = _db.Posts.ToList();
  var post = posts.Where(m => m.Id.Equals(id));
  var cats = _db.Categories.ToList(); 
  CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();

  categoryViewModel.Posts = post;
  categoryViewModel.Categories = cats;

  return View(categoryViewModel);
}
```

And finally here is my view:

```html
<label for="postCategory">Category</label>
<select>
@foreach (var cats in Model.Categories)
{
   <option value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => cats.Id)">
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => cats.Title)
   </option>
}
</select>
```

My question is how to make something like this in view:

```html
<option value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => cats.Id)" **if(post.Category = cats.Id){ print selected }**>
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => cats.Title)
</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change your ForEach Loop like this:

```
@foreach (var cats in Model.Categories)
{
    <!option value="@cats.Id" @((@Model.Posts.FirstOrDefault == cats.Id) ? "selected" : string.Empty)>@cats.Title()</!option>
}
```

Important ist the ! in the  tag.